# DataGridTemplateColumn BeginEdit on selection

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I subclassed `DataGridTemplateColumn` to define a custom column type. I use the following code to initialize the edit mode.

```
    protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(
        FrameworkElement editingElement, RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
    {
        editingElement.MoveFocus(
            new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.First));
        return base.PrepareCellForEdit(editingElement, editingEventArgs);
    }

    private void MyTextControlGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = sender as MyTextControl;
        if (control != null)
        {
            control.SelectAll();
        }            
    }
```

The problem is that `PrepareCellForEdit` gets only called after I 1) clicked into the cell and 2) clicked again to enter edit mode.

With `DataGridTextColumn` I can select the cell and type in some text to immediately enter edit mode without clicking again. I want the same behaviour for my column type.

The question is, how can I handle a KeyDown event on the cell to call `DataGridOwner.BeginEdit` in my `DataGridTemplateColumn` class. I tried to add a `PreviewKeyDown` handler to the control inside the `CellTemplate` but the event does not get fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally came up with this soultion:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="C1">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

The important part is `Focusable=False` (don't know why). Otherwise the `IsSelected` trigger works only for the first selection.